# jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I am trying to connect my project to MySQL but I keep getting an error I am not familiar with and everything seems to be correct , This is spring boot Multi Modular Project
MY main class - Module admin-rest

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.valentine.domain"})
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.valentine.adminportal", "com.valentine.service", "com.valentine.utility"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.valentine.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class AdminPortalApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AdminPortalApplication.class, args);
    }
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.format_sql=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookstoredb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=user
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

spring.datasource.platform=mysql

spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1


spring.jpa.properties.hbm2ddl=update

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
}
```

And my domain models are in another module called domain as you can see from my Entity scan in Main class

MY pom file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.valentine</groupId>
        <artifactId>onlinestore</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.valentine.onlinestore</groupId>
    <artifactId>admin-rest</artifactId>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.valentine.onlinestore</groupId>
            <artifactId>service-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.valentine.onlinestore</groupId>
            <artifactId>service</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.valentine.onlinestore</groupId>
            <artifactId>utility</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.valentine.onlinestore</groupId>
            <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
            <artifactId>dozer-spring</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
            <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- this is added to check weather user logged in or not-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--for checking -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Errors and Exception

```
Thu Jan 18 02:28:05 MSK 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
02:28:05.850 [main] ERROR o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'bookstoredb'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:873)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1710)
        at com.valentine.adminportal.AdminPortalApplication.main(AdminPortalApplication.java:18)
02:28:05.866 [main] WARN  o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup - Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'bookstoredb'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:339)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:366)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72)
    at com.valentine.adminportal.AdminPortalApplication.main(AdminPortalApplication.java:18)
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'bookstoredb'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:326)
    ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'bookstoredb'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:873)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1710)
```

I have basically everything required to make a connection and create tables in MySQL But to no avail , Any help please will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this line:

`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'bookstoredb'`

Looks like your database name was incorrect. Did you already double checked it? How did you create your database? You might want also to check the configuration of `mysql` on your XAMPP or whatever local server you use.

Comment: how do I check the configuration of the local server ? usually where is it located ? and Thank you yes my name of db did not tally

Comment: How do I automatically generate schema which I will later use for my H2 Schema.sql @you Awesum

Comment: If you use `XAMPP` you can see your configuration at `XAMPP -> mySQL->Settings(i think)->*.config` you'll see the config files there. Open it and you can change your settings there eg. db password, username etc. Instead of generating a schema, IMHO it would be easier if you create your tables beforehand and connect it to your application after. :)

Comment: but if I want to do what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to MySql database service. To resolve, just **Restart your MySQL service**

**How to restart the MySQL service** 
On Windows: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-adminsitration/restart-mysql 
On Linux:    https://linuxhint.com/restart-mysql-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227)